# Are the From and To stations in Indian train tickets only about seating?

Tags: tickets, india, seating, indian-railways

I've seen in mentioned in a few places online that when you book a ticket from point A to point B in a train, you automatically get the right to travel from the originating point O of the train till the terminal point T, except that you only get your own seat/berth during the duration it's traveling from A to B.

That sounds pretty preposterous, but I've seen it repeated enough times that I wonder if it's true.

Answer (score 4):

No, when you book a ticket from point A to B then you have the right to travel only from A to B. That is because you pay only for the journey from A to B and not O to T.

If there are other passengers who book tickets from O to A or B to A, the same seat might be allotted to them for those legs of the journey. In case there are no bookings for those legs, the seat will be vacant.